# Slow joining on primary key in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.4 on Windows 10 and have observed this strange slowness.

```
create table stock_prices (
    quote_date timestamp,
    security_id int NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (quote_date, security_id)
);
create index stock_prices_idx2 on stock_prices (security_id, quote_date);
```

Doing the following was instantaneous.

```
select * from stock_prices where quote_date = '2017-12-29';
```

But the following took 31s.

```
create temp table ts (
    quote_date timestamp,
    primary key (quote_date)
);

insert into ts values ('2017-12-29');

select p.* 
from stock_prices p, ts t
where p.quote_date = t.quote_date;

drop table ts;
```

AFAIK, the above should hit the index. Using DBeaver's explain execution plan function, it's reporting that it did a "Seq Scan" on stock_prices, which I assume means table scan.

Before I moved to Postgres 10.4, I was using SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition with the exact same schema and didn't have any issues. The database is quote big so I couldn't really provide much test data, but the underlying data was straight from Wharton Business School's WRDS academic research database (the table I'm using is CRSP.dsf). Any idea why postgres isn't using the index?

[Edit] Ok, looks like it hugely depends on what Postgres thinks is in the temp table `ts`. Adding `analyze ts;` before the `select` made it instantaneous. This is bizarre but anyway...

Comment: can you please provide the output if `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: I've posted it here https://explain.depesz.com/s/OdtE

Comment: It is totally normal, that the `ANALYZE ts` helps. The planner needs some statistics to decide on the best way to build the path. You should provide this information as an answer and accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a primary key/index on the `quote_date` column in the `ts` table.  Since you are doing an inner join here, the optimizer should be free to choose which table appears on the left and right sides of the join.  Assuming it puts the `stock_prices` table on the left side, then it could take advantage of that index on the `ts.quote_date` column.  But, in this case, it means it would be scanning the `stock_prices` table.  So, perhaps the query plan changed when you switched versions of Postgres, but I don't see anything unexpected here.  Postgres isn't using the index you asked about, because it seems to have found a better index/table to use.

Comment: But the query plan would suggest it's not using an index at all? I also tried dropped the primary key on the temp table and it's still very slow.

Comment: If it is in fact joining from `stock_prices` to `ts`, then it is likely that it would be using the index on `ts.quote_date`.  It has to scan one side of the join.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. See my comment on solving it. I've also posted the query plan here (https://explain.depesz.com/s/OdtE). Looks like Postgre was estimating the cost of execution to be way higher than it should (rows=12,199,595 vs. actual 7000 rows).

Comment: @swmfg Which makes sense.  If Postgres thinks `ts` would be huge, then it might go for scanning `stock_prices` to avoid having to scan `ts`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, adding `analyze ts` will solve the problem. Looks like statistics have a great deal of influence over how Postgre plans its query.